# Method with intents in service causes widget to FC

Tags: android, service, widget

I have made a service to handle my onClick intents in a widget. But it force closes when added to the screen, and I can't figure out why.

This is the method causing it to FC:

```
    public void onClick() {
    RemoteViews top=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);
    RemoteViews bottom=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);
    Intent clickintenttop=new Intent("android.tristan.widget.digiclock.CLICK1");
    Intent clickintentbottom=new Intent("android.tristan.widget.digiclock.CLICK2");
    PendingIntent pendingIntentClickTop=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickintenttop, 0);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentClickBottom=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickintentbottom, 0);
    bottom.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.BottomRow, pendingIntentClickBottom);
    top.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.TopRow, pendingIntentClickTop);
    int Top = appWidgetIds.length;
    int Bottom = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i=0; i<Top; i++)
    {
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], top);
    }
    for (int j=0; j<Bottom; j++)
    {
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[j], bottom);
    }
}
```

The method is getting called from the onCreate(). Anyone who can push me in the right direction?

EDIT: Taken from LogCat:

W/dalvikvm(22312): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(22312): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service android.tristan.widget.digiclock.IntentService: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3140)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:135)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2202)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.tristan.widget.digiclock.IntentService.onClick(IntentService.java:58)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.tristan.widget.digiclock.IntentService.onCreate(IntentService.java:40)

E/AndroidRuntime(22312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3125)

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the fc.  Use logcat: open the DDMS perspective in eclipse, or run `adb logcat` on the command line.

Comment: @tristan202 Is there no more stacktrace after the null pointer?  What line of code is the null pointer pointing to?

Comment: Well, it now seems that it is the onCreate() that causes the FC for some reason. I tried removing the call and replace it with a toast, and it crashed without showing the toast.

Comment: @Mayra I can't see what line of code it's pointing to. Is it to much to ask to let you take a look at the entire project if I zip it and upload it somewhere?

Comment: This tells you that it is caused by a null pointer at line 58 of IntentService, where you are trying to create a toast.  What is happening around there?  And no, sorry, I don't have time to do your debugging for you.  It is important skill to learn to read stacktraces and act upon them anyways.

Comment: @Mayra It is this line it's failing at:      RemoteViews top=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);

Comment: Are you sure?  It looks like the line that is failing is creating a toast.

Comment: Whenever you get a null pointer exception (or other fc), you need to examine the stacktrace, figure out which line of your code the error is referring to, and in the case of a null pointer figure out what on that line could possibly be null.   You can then split the line up into multiple lines, and add some null checks to figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Mayra I updated the logcat. I must have pasted an old one from when I tested with the toast. It is indeed the line where the remoteview get declared. I guess I must give up on this service thing at move it back into the main class.

Comment: Did you read my last comment?  Examine that line.  There are three things in that line that could possible be null : `context`, the package name returned by `context.getPackageName()` and `layoutID` (although if `layoutID` is an int, then it doesn't count).  The most likely culprit is context.  Did you check if that is null?

Comment: @Mayra I am a complete n00b, and have no clue what so ever how to check if it is null. I am not disgraceful, i really appreciate your help, but it is just a bit out of my league. I guess I'm in over my head.

Comment: @Mayra I'm thinking something like this at the beginning in onClick:        
if(context == null)
     {
            Context Icontext = new Context();

     }
But it is telling me that it cannot instantiate it.

Comment: No, you cannot create a new context like that.  You need to figure out why the context there is null.  Where are you getting it from?  What is the context surrounding this method?  Generally you get the context from either an Activity (which is-a Context), or the application.

Comment: @Mayra The context is my appwidgetprovider, but come to think of it, it is not referenced in the service. Am I getting warmer?

Comment: The code is within a service?  A Service is-a context, so why not just use this?

Comment: @Mayra Well, i have this as the first line in the class: public static Context context;
But that obviously isn't working for me.'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `context` is null.  You need to assign it to something before you can use it.  Or, if you are in a service, just use `this` since a Service is-a Context.

However, it sounds like you need a much better grasp of basic programming concepts beforeyou attempt anythign like this.  Go read through some basic Java tutorials, like [these Oracle ones](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), or check out some of the books or resources mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-java-books-websites-etc).

You are not yet ready to try to tackle Android.  Start from the basics, work up from there.